# Split Lua string into tables with subtables

Tags: lua, string-matching, lua-table

All the examples for splitting strings generate arrays.  I want the following

Given string like `x.y.z`  e.g. `storage.clusters.us-la-1`
How do I generate a table from that resembling

```
x = {
  y = {
    z = {
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a function that should do what you want.

```
function gen_table(str, existing)
  local root = existing or {}
  local tbl = root
  for p in string.gmatch(str, "[^.]+") do
    local new = tbl[p] or {}
    tbl[p] = new
    tbl = new
  end
  return root
end
```

Usage:

```
local t = gen_table("x.y.z")
local u = gen_table("x.y.w", t)
t.x.y.z.field = "test1"
t.x.y.w.field = "test2"
```

Comment: I'm parsing an ini file that has subsections like [section.subsection.sub] etc.. Thanks for the feedback I'll give it a try

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense.  Thanks heaps!

Comment: @Matt - You need to properly handle situations when new subsection is `x.y.z`, but `x.y` already exists.  The current solution will create another separate tree, but you need to merge your new subsection data into already existing tree.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: Added ability to modify an existing tree.